# Match string array parameter in other function parameter's parameters

Tags: typescript

Given this function

```
function Func(token: string, deps: string[], resolveFn: (...args: any[]) => any) {
    // Stuff
}
```

My goal is for the `resolveFn`'s arguments to match the dependencies.

Example this would be valid:
`Func('test', ['arg1', 'arg2'], (arg1: any, arg2: any) => {})`

This would not be valid:
`Func('test', ['arg1', 'arg2'], (hello: any, world: any) => {})`

This one is maybe more difficult but should also not be valid:
`Func('test', ['arg1', 'arg2'], (arg2: any, arg1: any) => {})`

Is this feasable?
Thank you

Comment: I think this is not possible. Parameter names can not really be observed by the type system. Given a function type, the implementer can still choose any name they want. There is no way to enforce a specific one to be used.

Comment: Yeah, parameter names are unobservable in TS so this is not possible.  See answers to linked questions for more info.  Good luck!